# Android radio button not visible while upgrading the android version

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

i was developing an application in android 2.3.3 then upgraded it to 4.0.3,now what is happing is the radio buttons are not visible on screen(though they are present/visible  in xml file ) but on click at their space their center part is visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the theme of the application through the Manifest.xml file .....

Hope that will help you in seeing the radio buttons because it changes the UI of the application...

Comment: thanx ,but why is  it so,that  it is working for dialog theme,and what if i don't want to use dialog theme

Comment: there are many other themes other than dialog themes..... like   android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar    etc.....

Comment: no i mean theme is required compulsory,so without applying any theme it will not work

Comment: the default theme provided by ICS is the one you getting it previously(the one you were complaining)... so if you dont like it you have to change it manually through the manifest.xml....

Answer (score 0):

Yes after upgrading it to 4.0.3, it won't be visible.. it happened to me also. You have to check in the layout API's like simple_list_item1, item2, dropdown etc...